# Bash Parsing of sectioned output of a command for specific lines

Tags: bash, awk

I have a command that outputs a bunch of lines as below 
First digit is section second digit represents key word.
I would like to be able to parse for keywords 2 3 and 5. 
Input

```
11
12
13
14
15
\n
\n
\n
21
22
23
24
25
\n
\n
\n
(2 more sections as such)
```

Output

```
12
13
15
\n
22
23
25
\n 
(continues for other 2 sections)
```

grep gave me
    12
    22
    13
    23
    15
    25
    (etc..)
I wasn't quite sure how to do it with awk.
My final goal is to put this into a script where the output of the parsing section (or line) goes to a temp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk with setting `RS`

```
awk '{while(++i<=NF)if($i~/[235]$/)print $i;i=0;print ""}' RS="" file
```

output:

```
12
13
15

22
23
25
```

**EDIT**

```
 awk '/^\s*$/{a[NR];if(!(NR-1 in a))print} /[235]$/{print}' file
```

Comment: so in this case whre it says [235] is where i would set the key values? how would this work for text?

Comment: then you need give the matching criteria for your text. as long as regex can match your required text, the line would work.

Comment: the issue i have fond with this code is that it only prints the word I am searching for not the whole line. Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: I can't seem to get it to match text instead of numbers. Would searching for words in lines change the code?

Comment: i suggest you make a new question. you didn't mention what kind of text do you want to match. take a look the example in your question, just said ending with 2,3,5. the two awk lines both do that for you. one is field based, one is row based.  A new question may be better. write proper example, also explain your match criteria clearly.

Comment: ok. I was trying to be generic to allow for a wider audience.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
$ awk '$1~/[235]$/{p=1;print}!$1&&p{p=0;print}' file
12
13
15

22
23
25
```

To separate the records with only a single linebreak the flag `p` is used, we set `p` when we print a match in the first block and when we reach the first blank line after each record i.e. `!$1` we print the blank line and unset the flag so to ignore the next two.

Comment: If I change the [235] to words would it still work? and the file at the end is the file i am reading from. Would it be possible to pipe a command's out put into this?

Comment: You can do any regex match you like and yes piping is not a problem.